# Find an isomorphism from the additive group Z_6 to the multiplicative group of Units U_7 in Z_7

Tags: abstract-algebra

I understand what is isomorphism, and i know that the identity element in $Z_6$ which is $[0]$should be mapped to the identity elements in $U_7$ which is $[1]$ and so $f([0]_6) = [1]_7$ and i also know that inverses should be mapped to inverses , for instance if we take $f([1]_6) = [3]_7$ then we must take $f([5]_6) = [5]_7$. And we can keep trying this way until we find an isomorphism , my question is , is there a way to know which elements should map to which elements without trial ?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do this. Can you indicate how much abstract algebra you know? For example, have you seen rings/fields and UFDs?

Comment: it's my first course in abstract algebra and we didn't touch ring theory yet !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $U_7$ are both cyclic.  If $\phi$ is an isomorphism from one to the other, it must satisfy $\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$ for any $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}_6$.

For this to occur, generators must map to generators. Further, the isomorphism is entirely determined by the image of a generator.  (Why?)

Comment: clearly [1] is a generator for $Z_6$ and $[3]$ is a generator for $U_7$ , but what do you mean mapping generators ! ?

Comment: In other words, I claim that the isomorphism must take $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ to $3$ in $U_7$.  If a supposed isomorphism took a generator and sent it to a non-generating element, then there is a contradiction to be found.

Comment: sorry if i seem stupid , but can you explain an example where a contradiction may occur , i still don't get the idea

Comment: Note that, since an isomorphism is injective, only the identity in $Z_6$ can map to the identity in $U_7$.  Now let $x$ be a generator in $Z_6$, and suppose it maps to a non-generating element in $U_7$ -- let's call it $y$.  Well, $y$ has some order that divides $6$.  Let's suppose it's order was $2$.  Then we'd get $\phi(x^2) = \phi(x)\phi(x) = y^2 = 1$.  But this is a contradiction: $x^2$ is not the identity in $Z_6$, but it's mapping to the identity in $U_7$.